# XSL Transformation with dynamic XML Tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML that looks similar to this:

```
<Element>
    <ele.Name> Name_Value </ele.Name>
    <ele.Age> Age_Value </ele.Age>
    <ele.Something> Something_Value </ele.Something>
<Element>
```

The Tags themselves are, except for the "ele" part completely dynamic and there can be any number of tags. Meaning there can be 100 different tags, none of them are known beforehand. Only the "ele" part inside the tag.

Now I need to transform the above XML into something like this:

```
Name;Age;Something
Name_Value;Age_Value;Something_Value
```

Two Lines, with the tag names in the first line and the values in the second. "ele" must be eliminated from the names. My current problem is that i dont really know how i can access those tags without knowing them beforehand. Maybe someone can give me a hint to find a solution to this problem?

Performance is very relevant here since this might be executed 10000+ times in a single process.

Comment: *"there can be 100 different tags ... this might be executed 10000+ times in a single process."* Then your XML cannot look similar to what you posted.

Comment: Well I didnt want to lay out my problem 1:1. Only the part where i am stuck right now.
The files i have to process is multiple gigabytes big with a depth of 10+. 
When I solve this problem i think i should be able to progress with my task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can process

```
<xsl:template match="Element">
  <xsl:value-of select="*/substring-after(local-name(), '.')" separator=";"/>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="*" separator=";"/>
</xsl:template>
```

that assumes XSLT 2 or later. But of course processing `*` is possible in XSLT 1.0 as well to process all child elements.

Comment: This pretty much helped. I had to adjust it quite a bit to fit my exact problem but the principle helped. Thank you a lot